# click function only available above 1024px breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mute button that I only want to work above screen width 1024.
The function should not be available below the mentioned break point. I have tried a couple of ways but still not able to achieve this. Any pointers would be helpful. Please see my snippet below:

```js
if($(window).width() > 1024) { 
     $("#mute").click(function() {

         if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
             $("video").prop('muted', false);
             $(this).removeClass("fa-volume-off");
             $(this).addClass("fa-volume-up");

         } else {
             $("video").prop('muted', true);
             $(this).removeClass("fa-volume-up");
             $(this).addClass("fa-volume-off");

         }
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet has syntax errors, and you haven't described what the issue with your code is. How does the snippet above differ from what you're trying to achieve? If you'd like to remove the event if the window shrinks, change it to `$("#mute").on("click" ...`, and you can remove it by doing `$("#mute").off("click");`

Comment: last `}`  need to be `});` and what problem you are facing right now?

Comment: @AlivetoDie made the change, getting syntax error now 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )'

Comment: @Santi issue with the code is that if statement around screen width has some errors. breaks the button completely

Comment: sorry swap last  two `}` and `});` with each-other. also still we don't know what problem you are facing apart from this?

Comment: the button works fine without the screenwidth if statement so its a case of fixing the screenwidth if statement that im having difficulty with.

Comment: Other than what @Santi has suggested, you could also swap the `if` that checks the width of the window to the `click` event binding. Basically, what I'm saying is bind the event handler but the event handler does the checking of the width and will only do stuff if the window size is `1024px` or more.

Comment: So put the width check inside the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed javascript error, It should work now.

```
if($(window).width() > 1024) { 
     $("#mute").click(function() {

         if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
             $("video").prop('muted', false);
             $(this).removeClass("fa-volume-off");
             $(this).addClass("fa-volume-up");

         } else {
             $("video").prop('muted', true);
             $(this).removeClass("fa-volume-up");
             $(this).addClass("fa-volume-off");

         }
     });
  }
```

Comment: still not going to work if the browser starts out small

Answer (score 1):

I think, You should check for the window width if there was a resize and then perform the necessary action.
Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    if(window.width < 1024)
    {
      $("#mute").off("click");
    }
    else
    {
      $("#mute").click(function() {
        . . .
      })
    }
  });

  $("window").trigger("resize"); // On trigger resize to make button active if window is already > 1024
})
```

Comment: @Livingstone what he means is that with your solution the button wouldn't work unless you resize the window first.

Comment: ah ya sorry, you could do a `$("window").trigger("resize");` after to simulate one resize, or is this a bad soultion?

Comment: You'll just have to update your answer to reflect your last comment.

Comment: This adds unneeded complexity, and load on the client, and is plain wrong. What if size > 1024px and user enlarges width even more? Then the else statement fires and you have 10-20-50-100 click handlers...

Answer (score 1):

You're adding click handler when executing the code, not when doing the click. when width > 1024px at the time you execute that code the handler gets created and will still work when width drops below 1024px. Similarly when execute that code and width < 1024px then the click handler will never be created!

So, try this code (inside $.ready or similar):

```
$("#mute").click(function() {

  if ($(window).width() <= 1024) return; // maybe return false;

  if ($("video").prop('muted')) {
    $("video").prop('muted', false);
    $(this).removeClass("fa-volume-off");
    $(this).addClass("fa-volume-up");

  } else {
    $("video").prop('muted', true);
    $(this).removeClass("fa-volume-up");
    $(this).addClass("fa-volume-off");

  }
});
```

EDIT: as already commented above while I was answering...

Answer (score 0):

Just try to swap the `if` statement with the `click` event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mute").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
      alert("Clicked");
    }
  });
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/30/) for you to test.